# Best way to inject packets into linux kernel to emulate ethernet packet arrival

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I am writing a `linux` kernel module for some tunnelling activity. The module will get packets from the networking stack and perform some operations on it. What is the best possible way to inject packets into the stack from the bottom(emulate ethernet packet arrival on wire) so that the packet traverses the entire receive path and is delivered to my module.

My module uses the kernel `br_handle_frame_hook` hook to get the packet which means that it cannot co-reside with the linux native `bridge` module. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [TAP](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt;h=c0aab985bad9ac4a159ea9f96e837bee28475291;hb=b69f0859dc8e633c5d8c06845811588fe17e68b3) device is what you are looking for - a nice way to send/receive Ethernet packets from user-space

Comment: Can I use TAP non-programmatically. I mean create a TAP interface and then run tcpreplay traffic on that. Will that work?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using NetFilter

http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=61&id=13

TAP would be great, if you're working in user space, which you're not

Comment: What about creating a TAP device and then doing tcpreplay on that interface. Will those packets then travel up the networking stack? i think they should

Comment: @Varda Elentári  If there are IP table rules which conflict with the C code to accept/reject or forward packets, how is that controlled? By setting priority? What if both conflicting ones are set to NF_IP_PRI_FIRST

Answer (score -1):

I recommend tap like @raber before me. I also recommend reading this excelet tutorial: http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/ .

You asked whether you can make the tap non-programatically and then replay traffic into it. The answer is yes. Look for the 'persistency' options (which b.t.w. can also be done programatically with a short tool you can write yourself if you prefer not to download tools that can already do it). You may also want/need to define the user that may use the tap (or otherwise just sudo your operations).